# Visual Studio: Service Reference dialog will not open

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

Even without selecting a WSDL, if I click on the Advanced button on the Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio 2008 on a specific project, I get the following error:

An error occured while parsing EntityName.  Line 2, position 47.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

this must be problem of your webservice class, there might be some errors in that.

Comment: Which webservice class would you be refering to?  I get the error even before creating the service.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new projects and transferring all of my files over.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL published from the server may be broken, you may try the command line tool (svcutil) to test it, though the VS uses the same tool indeed.